# outlook huge attachment management

Tags: outlook, vsto, mapi

I'm going to develop an outlook plugin that detach huge attachments from the email and upload such attachments to an FTP site.

In my first version of the plugin i did all the work in the Application.ItemSend event, but when the attachment are really huge (greater than 1GB)  this solution is unsatisfied because the UI freezes while the user uploads the file.

A mandatory requirement is that the email should be send only after that the upload to the ftp site is finished. Any ideas about a better way to implement an outlook solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the UI freezes while you upload the file? Display a modal dialog while the upload is still in progress and do the actual upload on a separate thread.

Comment: yes, the UI freezes while i upload the files.It would be nice that the mailitem is moved to the outbox folder when the user click on the send button so that outlook is available for other task. This will be the same behaviour of the ordinary mailitem. The upload of the attachment should be done in background and the mailitem should remain in the outbox folder until the upload is finished. My problem is that i don't know how to manage such mail item in the outbox folder

Comment: When ItemSend event fires, start a timer (you need to be out of the event handler to be able to do a few things). When the timer fires, disable it (so it won't fire again), move the message to the Outbox folder, save the attachments (you can only do that on the main thread) and start your upload on a secondary thread. When the upload finishes, delete the attachments, call MailItem.Send (make sure you don't process the same item twice).